# Setting up PHP 5.4 with IIS 7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

So I have been following the instructions on the PHP website, but I still cannot get it to work properly. I guess the part that I am most confused about is setting up directives in the php.ini file.

In particulay *this step*: `extension` = `xxxxx.dll` - For each extension you wish to enable, you need a corresponding "extension=" directive that tells PHP which extensions in the `extension_dir` to load at startup time.

Not sure what its for...

If I am trying to set up a form that onsubmit sends an email using the POST method how which extension files should I use?

using this guide to help me out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: you don't need ANY extensions for a simple form->email script. PHP has all of those capabilities built-in.

Comment: @MarcB even if I am using the mail function and POST?

Comment: Yes `mail()` is a core function it isn't part of an extension. `$_POST` is also part of core php. You will have to configure php for mail to work correctly though. You will need some type of smtp server to be running locally or one that allows you to relay.